# Why is this AS400 DB2 select case surprisingly resolving to null?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have the following `case` expression inside a query yielding a `null` on column `per_pack_qty`:

```
select
    global_override.SHIS8,
    case    
        when sbsize = 8 and 
             global_override.SHIS8 is not null and 
              trim(global_override.SHIS8) not in ('', '0') 
        then global_override.SHIS8
        else sbsizu
    end as per_pack_qty

from 
    order s
    left join order_override on order_override.orfile = s.sbfile
    left join global_override on global_override.shfile = s.sbfile

where
    sbfile in (5859480, 5859490)
    and SBBX0 = 343
limit 1
```

Running yields per_pack_qty of `null` and SHIS8 of "0".

However, if I put a concat around `global_override.SHIS8` like:

```
[...] then concat(global_override.SHIS8, '') [...]
```

Then the case resolves to *`sbsizu`*.

Does a null value as the `then` sub-expression somehow cause the entire case expression to evaluate to null?  Is AS400 DB2 picky about all branches on a case expression yielding the same type?  Why does the `concat` wrapper make this work?

Comment: The `then` clause does not determine which of the `case` expressions evaluate to true.  Something is amiss in your explanation.

Comment: There is no check for sbsizu=null, so that column is probably null.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I totally agree that is how `case` expressions work. I'm not even modifying the case expression branch logic.  I only modify the result with a `concat()` wrapper.  You're never supposed to blame the compiler which is why I'm asking here, but it almost feels like a bug, because I only change the `then` sub-expression.

Comment: @Tomc, `sbsizu` is "133  " in this case.  Once I change `then global_override.SHIS8` to `then concat(global_override.SHIS8, '')` the default case of `sbsizu` is taken which results in "133  ".  It is truly bizarre behavior to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. AS400 (IBM i) expects all branches on a case expression to yield the same type. The type of outcome is determined by the first branch. It returns `null` when the data type of outcome is different from the data type of first branch. By using the `concat` wrapper, the type of outcome is changed to string.

Comment: Well done. I think most other sql variants wouldn't do this, so good catch.

Comment: It works as long as outcome of case expression can be converted into data type of first branch. This is true for AS400 (DB2 for i) and DB2 LUW. It is possible that sbsizu has some non printable characters, may be x'00'. If outcome can not be converted into data type of first branch, AS400 returns null and DB2 LUW returns error SQL0420N. Oracle returns error ORA-00932 even when outcome can be converted into data type of first branch.

Comment: @TomC . . . All databases return a single type for a `case` expression.  However, most (all?) would return a type conversion error if the conversion fails.  Does DB2 really not return an error in this case?  Based on this line in the documentation, "The attributes of the result are determined according to the rules that are described in Rules for result data types", I would expect DB2 to attempt type conversion and get an error (if it fails) -- just as with any other database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, It is surprising to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this is your problem:

```
where sbfile in (5859480, 5859490) and SBBX0 = 343
limit 1
```

The `limit 1` suggests that the rest of the query would return multiple rows.  There is no `order by`.  Hence, the specific row being returned is indeterminate.  It could even vary on multiple executions of the same query on the same data on the same hardware.

So, I assume that your issue is that different rows are being returned in the queries you are running.

Comment: There are 4 results without the limit and all of them return null. Sorry for the unnecessary detail.